# how to reset the value of a dropdown to firstvalue after an action is perfomed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below simple dropdown component

```
import React,  { Fragment } from 'react';

export default class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.props.handleSelect(event);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <select className="dd-wrapper" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {this.props.list.map((item) => (
                        <option className="dd-list-item" key={item.name} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>)
                    )}                  
                </select>
            </Fragment>    


        );
    }
}
```

I'm using this component in some other place as below along with NewMeasureDialogue component.Now,When I select 'Base Measure' from the dropdown and clicked on NewMeasureDialogue 'onYesClicked'.The value from BaseMeasure should be changed to Calculated Measure.

```
export class ParentComponent {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                measures: [{
                    name: 'Calculated Measure',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Base Measure'
                }
                ]

            }
        }
handleDropDownSelect = (event) => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedValue: event.target.value,
                        isBaseMeasure: event.target.value === 'Base Measure' ? true : false
                    })
                }
        render() {


            return (
<div>
                <SimpleDropdown list={this.state.measures} handleSelect={this.handleDropDownSelect} />
                <NewMeasureDialogue msg={StringConstants.NEW_MEASURE_DIALOGUE_TEXT} show={this.state.show} close={this.close} onYesClicked={this.onYesClicked} />
</div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to change the dropdownvalue when onYesclicked is performed on NewMeasure Dialogue.

Comment: Can you please format your code so that it's readable and correct? You have invalid code such as the multi-component return in `render` of `ParentComponent` (you must wrap these in a Fragment, array or another JSX element). You are also defining your method `handleDropDownSelect ` within `render` instead of at the class level.

Comment: Also side note, you don't need to do the binds in your constructor if you are using arrow functions. Arrow functions bind the function to this already.

Answer (score 0):

in order to achieve this, you may want to convert your `SimpleDropdown` into a fully controlled component, meaning it should accept not only `handleSelect` method, but also a `value` property

```
import React,  { Fragment } from 'react';

export default class SimpleDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.props.handleSelect(event);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>                                 
                <select className="dd-wrapper" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {this.props.list.map((item) => (
                        <option 
                            className="dd-list-item"
                            key={item.name}
                            value={item.name}
                        >
                            {item.name}
                        </option>
                    ))}                  
                </select>
            </Fragment>    


        );
    }
}
```

and do some modification in `ParentComponent`

```
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: '',
            measures: [{
                name: 'Calculated Measure',
            },
            {
                name: 'Base Measure'
            }
            ]
        }
    }

    handleDropDownSelect = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedValue: event.target.value,
            isBaseMeasure: event.target.value === 'Base Measure' ? true : false
        })
    }

    onYesClicked = () => {
        this.setState({selectedValue: 'Calculated Measure'})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SimpleDropdown 
                    list={this.state.measures}
                    handleSelect={this.handleDropDownSelect}
                    value={this.state.selectedValue}
                />
                <NewMeasureDialogue
                    msg={StringConstants.NEW_MEASURE_DIALOGUE_TEXT}
                    show={this.state.show}
                    close={this.close}
                    onYesClicked={this.onYesClicked}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```